# Does Qt5 have any class for similar to StringBuilder or StringBuffer?

Tags: c++, qt, stream, qt5

Surprisingly, Qt5 has deprecated the `StringBuilder` class that was present in previous versions. My other option is to use `QTextStream`, which is not convenient since I have to pass in the buffer where it writes (e.g. `QFile`, `QString`).

C++ (`std::stringstream`), C# (`StringBuilder`) and Java (`StringBuffer`) have these classes. How about Qt?

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why do you think the StringBuilder mechanism is disabled in Qt5?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=qstringbuilder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QStringBuilder` is not deprecated. From Qt [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html):

> In 4.6, an internal template class QStringBuilder has been added along with a few helper functions. This class is marked internal and does not appear in the documentation, because you aren't meant to instantiate it in your code. Its use will be automatic, as described below. The class is found in src/corelib/tools/qstringbuilder.cpp if you want to have a look at it.

Their code sample:

```
#include <QStringBuilder>

QString hello("hello");
QStringRef el(&hello, 2, 3);
QLatin1String world("world");
QString message =  hello % el % world % QChar('!');
```

And you can use everything from C++ you need like `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Just be very careful, in C++11, not to write `auto string = hello % world;`.

Comment: I may have been wrong when said QStringBuilder is deprecated, but it's not a class like StringBuffer in Java or StringBuilder in C#. std::stringstream is an alternative, but I'd rather use a Qt class. Ideally I want to have something like this: QStringBuilder stringBuilder; stringBuilder << "hello, world";....

Comment: If QString is not enough for you, you can always use C++ classes like std::stringstream. Also you can always convert between std::string and QString, this is not bad